STM32C031 Number of Conversion can not be more than 8
I am trying to make a STM32CubeMX design with STM32C031. I have 11 ADC channels to read but I can only select 8 of them STM32CubeMX does not allow me to select more. Is there any reason for that?

My second question is what is the difference between
sequencer set to fully configurable and sequencer set not to fully configurable
Is there a limit to read ADC channel in STM32C versions?

STM32C031 supports two different modes of channel sequencer configurations:

Not fully configurable: This mode is similar to the one present in STM32F0 series. You can enable each channel (more than 8), but they are scanned in ascending or descending order (descending order isn't available on F0 series). For example you can enable and scan in 0->4->7 or 7->4->0 order, but not in 0->7->4 order.
Fully configurable: This mode is similar to the one present in STM32F4 series (but somewhat more limited on C0 series). You can configure the scanning in any order. For example, 0->7->4 order is possible in this mode. However, you can select maximum 8 channels in this mode. In comparison, STM32F4 doesn't have this limitation.

So, if you need to scan more than 8 channels, you need to use "not fully configurable" mode.

0
If ı want to you use ''Not fully configurable'' adjusment. Will it enough to use HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1,ADC_Converted[11],11)? And they will count as Ch0 = ADC_Converted[0].... Ch11 = ADC_Converted[11] right? Or do ı have to make some adjustment too?

@Engineer I use my own HAL, so unfortunately I'm not familiar with the ST's HAL library functions. But I guess HAL_ADC_Start_DMA() usage is independent of the channel sequencer mode.

Thank you for all. Could you explain to me Scan Convertion mode, Continous Convertion Mode and DMA Continues Requests? If ı want to use ''Not fully configurable'' which ones should ı choose?
